# Link.click gives "Permission denied" error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was working on a code which scrapes vessel data from a website. But when there are more than one match, i am trying to show list of all vessels with country in input box. In input box user will enter the index number of ship he is searching for and he will get desired results. In this code lnk.click is giving "permission denied error. i am not able to figure out how to resolve this and get proper results in every case. Here is my code:

```
Dim ie As Object, ieDoc As Object, lnk As Object, a, nrec, num, fin As String
    Dim j As Variant
    Dim IMO As String, MMSI As String, Flag As String, DWT As String, VType As String, YBuilt As String
    Dim IMOA(0 To 50) As String, MMSIA(0 To 50) As String, FlagA(0 To 50) As String, DWTA(0 To 50) As String, VTypeA(0 To 50) As String, YBuiltA(0 To 50) As String

Sub hull_data_by_Ashish()

For Each cell In Selection
a = UCase(Trim(cell.Value))
Call hullByAshish
ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, 5).Value = VType
ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, 6).Value = IMO
ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, 7).Value = YBuilt
ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, 8).Value = Flag
ActiveSheet.Cells(cell.Row, 9).Value = DWT
'ie.Quit
Next cell
End Sub

Private Sub hullByAshish()
    'Dim IMO As String, MMSI As String, Flag As String, DWT As String, VType As String, YBuilt As String

    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    a = "Paragon MSS2"

    With ie
        .Navigate "https://www.marinetraffic.com/en/ais/index/search/all/keyword:" & a
        .Visible = False
    End With

    Do While ie.readyState <> 4: Wait 5: Loop

    DoEvents

    Set ieDoc = ie.document

    For Each lnk In ieDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
        If lnk.innerHTML = a Then
        nrec = Split(Split(ie.document.body.innerHTML, "Found <strong>")(1), "</strong> records")(0)
        If nrec = 1 Then
            lnk.Click
            Else
            For j = 1 To nrec
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
            lnk.Click

            Do While ie.readyState <> 4: Wait 5: Loop
            VTypeA(j) = GetType
            'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
            IMOA(j) = GetValue("IMO:")
            'MMSI = GetValue("MMSI:")
            YBuiltA(j) = GetValue("Year Built:")
            FlagA(j) = GetValue("Flag:")
            DWTA(j) = GetValue("Deadweight:")
            Next j
            num = "1 - " & IMOA(1) & " - " & FlagA(1)
            For i = 2 To nrec
            num = num & vbCrLf & i & IMOA(i) & " - " & FlagA(i)
            Next i
            fin = InputBox(num, nrec & " - " & " records found for a. please select right one.")
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next lnk

    Do While ie.readyState <> 4: Wait 5: Loop

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    VType = GetType
    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    IMO = GetValue("IMO:")
    'MMSI = GetValue("MMSI:")
    YBuilt = GetValue("Year Built:")
    Flag = GetValue("Flag:")
    DWT = GetValue("Deadweight:")

    'Debug.Print "Vessel Type: " & VType
    'Debug.Print "IMO: " & IMO
    'Debug.Print "MMSI: " & MMSI
    'Debug.Print "Year Built: " & YBuilt
    'Debug.Print "Flag: " & Flag
    'Debug.Print "Deadweight: " & DWT
    ie.Quit
End Sub

Function GetValue(s As String) As String
   'Debug.Print s
   If InStr(ie.document.body.innerHTML, s) <> 0 Then
   GetValue = Trim(Split(Split(Split(Trim(Split(ie.document.body.innerHTML, s)(1)))(0), "<b>")(1), "</b>")(0))
   End If
End Function
Function GetType() As String
   'Debug.Print s
   If InStr(ie.document.body.innerHTML, "Vessel Type: <b") <> 0 Then
   GetType = Replace(Replace(Split(Split(Split(ie.document.body.innerHTML, "Vessel Type: <b")(1), "text-dark")(1), "</b>")(0), """", ""), ">", "")
   End If
End Function

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: @siddharth-rout you pointed me in a right direction when i started this code. I hope i can get some help here.

Comment: i did not get the error, but i did not get any data either. you are starting `Sub hull_data_by_Ashish`, and you are hoping that the correct cells on a correct sheet are selected at the time. your code repeats for every cell that is selected ... change `.Visible = False` to `.Visible = True` and you will see. i think that the website may be banning your IP. you need to change your code to do **one web page access** and scrape all the data you need.  ... also get rid of the `With ie ... End With` convention and use `ie.Navigate ...` and `ie.Visible ...` that will get rid of two useless lines

Comment: Not sure why you have the `Permission denied` error.  But I have tried you code, there is one line (`If lnk.innerHTML = a Then`) you will want to change to **`If LCase(lnk.getAttribute("title")) Like LCase("*" & a & "*") Then`** so that way it will save you some time and also match the criteria you have set.  The other recommendation will be changing the `Wait` to a function.  I can give you a sample but it is not an answer and it would be hard to write in this small comment box.

Comment: I think the problem is when you click into a new page, the whole source code becomes invalid from the prior page.  You will need to set the prior page to nothing and then set a new one for the new page.  Another thought is to break down each click page into small subroutines so that will be easier to manage.